# How to delete object from Realm Database Android?

Tags: android, database, realm

I want remove all message object from realm those are equal to userid

```
RealmQuery<Message> rowQuery = realm.where(Message.class).equalTo(Message.USER_ID, userId);
realm.beginTransaction();
//TODO : here I want to remove all messages where userId is equal to "9789273498708475"
realm.commitTransaction();
```

Answer (score 124, accepted):

In 0.88.3 and below you can do:

```
realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
    @Override
    public void execute(Realm realm) {
        RealmResults<Message> rows = realm.where(Message.class).equalTo(Message.USER_ID,userId).findAll();
        rows.clear();
    }
});
```

From 0.89 (next release) this will be `deleteAllFromRealm()` instead.

```
realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
    @Override
    public void execute(Realm realm) {
        RealmResults<Message> result = realm.where(Message.class).equalTo(Message.USER_ID,userId).findAll();
        result.deleteAllFromRealm();
    }
});
```

Comment: Just fyi it would be nice if there was a comment in the deprecated `.clear()` method that `.deleteAllFromRealm()` is now the correct method to use.

Comment: @EddieLee it's in the [0.89.0 change log](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#0890)

Comment: Imagine we have another model which has `RealmList<Message>`. If somehow we delete whole `Message` rows, does it delete on that Model too? (Please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49029813/realm-the-size-of-filled-realmlist-in-realmobject-is-zero)

Comment: realm.executeTransaction {
var result = realm.where(JsonValidate::class.java).equalTo("Transaction.Number",No).findAll();
result.deleteAllFromRealm()
}
I am using this query to delete, delete working fine but, I cant add again the same number it says "already existed"
How to resolve it.
Note: I dont want insertOrUodate method

Answer (score 11):

This must be done between the `realm.beginTransaction();` and the   `realm.commitTransaction();`   I also listed in the code example a few `args()`.

```
realm.beginTransaction();
MessageObject messageobj = realm.where(Message.class)
                         .findFirst()  //or
                         .greaterThan("age", 10) // implicit AND
                         .beginGroup() //or you can use
                         .equalTo("name", "Peter")
                         .or()
                         .contains("name", "Jo")
                         .endGroup()
                         .findAll();
messageobj.deleteFromRealm();
realm.commitTransaction();
```

Comment: `removeFromRealm()` must be done in write transaction (between `.beginTransaction()` & `.commitTransaction()`)

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional [context](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) regarding _how_ and/or _why_ it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now! Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/41421851/edit) your answer to add an explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. It also doesn't hurt to mention why this answer is more appropriate than others.

Answer (score 4):

this is how i Used it

```
  RealmResults<CartDBItems> rows= realm.where(CartDBItems.class).equalTo("id", id).findAll();;
         rows.deleteAllFromRealm();
```

Answer (score 2):

For below v10 realm android users. Given below will work fine

```
realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
    @Override
    public void execute(Realm realm) {
        RealmResults<Note> result = realm.where(Notes.class).equalTo(Note.NOTE_ID,noteID).findAll();
        result.deleteAllFromRealm();
    }
});
```

However, it will crash for v10 and above

```
Running transactions on the UI thread has been disabled.
```

Your app will not crash if you run execute transactions from the UI thread as long as you are running Realm prior to v10. For the upcoming v10 release we are introducing two new settings in `RealmConfiguration.Builder`, namely `allowWritesOnUiThread` and `allowQueriesOnUiThread`, which will allow users to control whether it is allowed to run transactions and/or queries from the UI thread.

```
RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
  .allowWritesOnUiThread(true)
  .build()
```

And it will work like it always has. So you can decide when/if you want to opt into the new behavior.

Answer (score 1):

```
 myRealm.beginTransaction();

     RealmResults<Datos> datos = myRealm.where(DatosCliente.class)
                        .equalTo("folio",FOLIO)
                        .findAll();

 datos.deleteAllFromRealm();
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate your answer and explain what this code does? This would be helpful for future visitors.