# Does Realm support physical delete on Android?

Tags: android, realm

Last day I started using Realm as Android storage rather than Sqlite.

Everything went well till I searched for some pros and cons; someone said that it doesn't support delete (I was shocked). but I found that there is a delete section in documentation and I implemented sample application that adds 150 row and then I 'delete' them as the [following answer said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36736415/1239911).

The size of list after deleteing is 0 which is logically right. But when I checked the size of myDB.realm file in the 'data/data/' path in the emulator, I found it the same size of the file before deleting. So does Realm flag items as deleted or physically deleting it?

Comment: Add more rows and see if the file size grows or stays the same. It is possible that it will reuse the space.

Comment: @cyroxis Yes, adding more rows increases the file size.

Comment: I tried @christian-melchior answer and it worked properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data is physically deleted, but right now Realm doesn't automatically reclaim the used space (it is on our TODO). In the mean time, you can manually call `Realm.compactRealm(realmConfig)` if you want to reclaim the space: https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/Realm.html#compactRealm-io.realm.RealmConfiguration-

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me when using Realm.compactRealm(realmConfig). But when I used the configuration that has been set in Application class like this Realm.compactRealm(mRealm.getConfiguration()); it didn't work. Any Idea?

Comment: You cannot compact an open Realm, which was most likely what was happening.