# How to delete object at index using Realm with Android

Tags: android, realm

How can I delete an object by it's index within the table when using Realm with Android? Please, note that the object does not have ID field that I can use to query on it. I know it's index in the table and want to use it for the deletion.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to delete object from Realm Database Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36736178/how-to-delete-object-from-realm-database-android)

Answer (score 1):

```
realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
     @Override
     public void execute(Realm realm) {
            RealmResults<MyObject> result = realm.where(MyObject.class).findAll();
            result.deleteFromRealm(index);
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

public void deletePerson(int personId, int position) {

RealmResultsresults=null;

results=myRealm.where(context).equalTo("id", personId).findAll();

myRealm.beginTransaction();

results.remove(0);

myRealm.commitTransaction();

personDetailsModelArrayList.remove(position);

personDetailsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}

Hi ,

I Hope This code will be use full to u.

This followed link is help full to u

http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/realm-mobile-database-implementation-in-android

Comment: The object does not have ID field that I can use to query on. I know it's index within the table and want to use it for deletion.