# Realm - results.remove() is deprecated in realm

Tags: android, realm

Now that **results.remove(0)** is deprecated in realm, what is the best way to remove the realm element in an android application?

I have tried to delete particular element and I have used following code :

using `result.deleteAllFromRealm();` it's delete all element but need to delete particular position.

```
RealmResults<PersonDetailsModel> results = myRealm.where(PersonDetailsModel.class).equalTo("id", personId).findAll();
        myRealm.beginTransaction();
        results.remove(0);     // App crash 
        myRealm.commitTransaction();
```

But it's app crash on that line and I am getting this error :

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: This method is not supported by 'RealmResults' or 'OrderedRealmCollectionSnapshot'.
```

Suggest some way to solved this issue.

Comment: Already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36736178/how-to-delete-object-from-realm-database-android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
realm.executeTransaction((r) -> {
    r.where(PersonDetailsModel.class).equalTo("id", personId).findAll().deleteAllFromRealm();
});
```

Or

```
realm.executeTransaction((r) -> {
    PersonDetailsModel person = r.where(PersonDetailsModel.class).equalTo("id", personId).findFirst();
    if(person != null) {
        person.deleteFromRealm();
    }
});
```

Comment: I only added this answer because the `deleteFromRealm(index)` call is unreliable, and nobody posted `object.deleteFromRealm`. So if someone opens this page and doesn't go to the duplicate, they'll see mostly wrong answers. I have no guilty conscience over closing this as duplicate, nor providing an answer over the others that contains the "canonical way".

Answer (score 1):

Use deleteFromRealm method

```
result.deleteFromRealm(index);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
        @Override
        public void execute(Realm realm) {
            RealmResults<PersonDetailsModel> result = realm.where(PersonDetailsModel.class).equalTo("id", personId).findAll();
            result.deleteAllFromRealm();
        }
    });
```

if didn't solve your issue then you can try below line:

```
result.deleteFromRealm(pos);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
result.deleteFromRealm(index);
```